# Teams Toolkit: read configurableProperties and add a custom configurable property

Tags: microsoft-teams

We need to "Customize our Teams app" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/enable-app-customization).
Is it possible to read configurableProperties from "Manifest schema for Microsoft Teams" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) using Teams Toolkit (for React) after an admin changed a property (e.g. websiteUrl) in our app?
And can I add custom configurable properties in the manifest?

Sincerely,
Maxim.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if these are readable from your app, but in any case you can't add your own. In addition, admins can't just change -any- property, only those listed in the page you linked (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema). This means, for instance, that they can't change the `websiteUrl` for your tab - your app will always render from the web url you supply. Admins can only basically change things that affect the 'branding' of your app (like the name, logo, descriptions, etc.). The 'website' settings here are things like the privacy policy, etc.